# Tabbar change tab bar controller items

Tags: ios, iphone, viewcontroller, tabbar

I have a tab bar controller with 5 view controllers. On the first tab I have a login screen and on logging in depending on the login one view controller of the tab view controllers has to be removed. I have tried doing:

```
 [delegate.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationController,
                                    [[delegate.tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1],
                                    [[delegate.tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:3],
                                    [[delegate.tabBarController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:4], 
                                    nil]];
```

But I get a crash with log:

```
-[__NSArrayI removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: The compiler says that you are trying to remove an NSArray from a superview thats why it is crashes. You actually have to remove a viewcontroller from the superview. Can you paste more code of how you remove the tabbar item you do not need after logging in?

Comment: @NikosM. Small correction, runtime (and not compiler) will raise this exception.

Comment: write your all code here.

Comment: I am using NGTabBar from https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGTabBarController/tree/master/NGTabBarController

Comment: I am also facing same issue. kindly update me how you resolved the crash.